# How do you switch between two request mappings handled by the same Spring MVC mapping handler?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/abc", "/def"} method = RequestMethod.GET)
public final String switch(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model) 
throws Exception {

// pseudeocode:
if mapping == "abc"
 return "redirect:/def";
else
 process the request;

}
```

I want to redirect to `def` if the `abc` handler is called.

Is it possible to do this in the same handler function that processes "def"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion it would be better if you create another method with @RequestMapping("abc"), which redirects to def. If you don't want to do that, you can get the path info from HttpServletRequest (look at the javadoc) and do an if statement to do the redirect.